# Arduino M0 pro(ATSAMD21G18A-U) to NEO-M8N-0-10 gps interface issue

Tags: gps, uart

i trying to interface ATSAMD21G18A-U to NEO-M8N-0-10 gps by using UART.
my problem is here, i  need to use pin 25(rx) and 26(tx) of arduino to interface. i have tried below. but getting

```
error:C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved2023420-9788-1he85tu.af3\sketch_may20a\sketch_may20a.ino:1:10: fatal error: SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

exit status 1

Compilation error: SoftwareSerial.h: No such file or directory
```

**Code:**

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(25, 26); // RX, TX pins for GPS module

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Serial monitor for debugging
  gpsSerial.begin(9600); // GPS module communication
}

void loop() {
  if (gpsSerial.available()) {
    char c = gpsSerial.read();
    Serial.print(c); // Print GPS data to Serial monitor
  }
}
```

I tried to download library but not able find. I am newbie to arduino.

Comment: use Serial1 on RX/TX pins